# Q: MYSQL Data tables suddenly missing

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform

Earlier today [11-09-2021] one of our databases from our production environment suddenly dropped it's table for reasons we don't know. This happened around after 4am, since we still had a snapshot of our drive for that time, which is weird as no one was using or accessing the server at the time. Can someone tell if this normally happens?

Comment: were any new tables created?  possibly containing a ransom note?  (yes, this really happens)

Answer (score 0):

This for sure its not normal behavior, you should check MySQL logs to see what was happening at that time.

In MySQL we need to see often 3 logs which are mostly important:

- `The Error Log.` It contains information about errors that occur while the server is running (also server start and stop)
- `The General Query Log`. This is a general record of what mysqld is doing (connect, disconnect, queries)
- `The Slow Query Log.` Ιt consists of "slow" SQL statements (as indicated by its name).

The one that will be your starting point is `The General Query Log`.

By default no log files are enabled in MYSQL. All errors will be shown in the syslog `(/var/log/syslog).`

To Enable them just follow below steps:

**1. Go to mysql conf file `(/etc/mysql/my.cnf)` and add following lines:**

**Enable general query log add following**

```
general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
general_log             = 1
```

**2. Save the file and restart mysql using following commands**

```
service mysql restart
```

To read content of the error log file in real time, run:

```
sudo tail -f $(mysql -Nse "SELECT CONCAT(@@datadir, @@general_log_file)")
```

Hope this will help you to find out what actually happened on your database server.